# go - How to get request message body content?

Tags: ajax, node.js, express, go, request

My client code sends an AJAX request to server, containing a message

How could I read data from that request message body. In Express of NodeJS, I use this:

```
    app.post('/api/on', auth.isLoggedIn, function(req, res){
                res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
                res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'POST');
                res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type');

                var url = req.body.url;
                // Later process
}
```

What is the `url = req.body.url` equivalent in Go?

Comment: I think I misunderstood the question.  Are you looking for equivalent Go code for the server handler of the POST, or for Go code demonstrating a client response?

Comment: @JohnWeldon Go code for server handler of the POST which includes getting body of the request message. I edited the question to make it clearer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here](https://play.golang.org/p/eI6YTlGaDo) is a simple example of an http handler:

```
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "net/http"
)

func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/", Handler)
    http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil)
    // Running in playground will fail but this will start a server locally
}

type Payload struct {
    ArbitraryValue string `json:"arbitrary"`
    AnotherInt     int    `json:"another"`
}

func Handler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    body, err := ioutil.ReadAll(r.Body)
    if err != nil {
        http.Error(w, err.Error(), http.StatusInternalServerError)
        return
    }

    url := r.URL
    // Do something with Request URL
    fmt.Fprintf(w, "The URL is %q", url)

    payload := Payload{}
    err = json.NewDecoder(bytes.NewReader(body)).Decode(&payload)
    if err != nil {
        http.Error(w, err.Error(), http.StatusInternalServerError)
        return
    }
    // Do something with payload

}
```

Comment: Yes, that works fine too.. I just munged some existing sample code for this example.

Answer (score 2):

If the request body is URL encoded, then use [r.FormValue("url")](https://godoc.org/net/http#Request.FormValue) to get the "url" value from the request.

If the request body is JSON, then use the [JSON decoder](https://godoc.org/encoding/json#Decoder) to parse the [request body](https://godoc.org/net/http#Request.Body) to a value typed to match the shape of the JSON.

```
var data struct {
   URL string
}
if err := json.NewDecoder(r.Body).Decode(&data); err != nil {
    // handle error
}
// data.URL is "url" member of the posted JSON object.
```